# InteractiveBrowserCredential doesn't show popup window sometimes

Tags: .net, wpf, azure, authentication, azure-storage

I have a WPF application using a connection to Azure Storage blobs. It works fine with the connection string, but I'd like to access blobs through Active Directory (with login window). The best solution seems to use **InteractiveBrowserCredential**, but I have a problem here - sometimes the popup window is shown and I'm authenticated and can get blobs successfully, but **sometimes the Browser popup window is not shown and the application hangs...** No errors are thrown.

I'm using InteractiveBrowserCredential like this:

```
var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri(...)), new InteractiveBrowserCredential());
```

then getting blobs by a prefix:

```
 var blobs = blobContainerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: prefix);
 var files = blobs.Select(b => ...);
 IEnumerable<string> res = files.AsParallel().Select(b => ...).ToArray(); //program hangs here
 return res;
```

And the program **sometimes** doesn't continue.

But if I call, for example:

```
blobContainerClient.Exists()
```

the program **always hangs and never execute...** (still any errors..)

I found a reported bug https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10083, where is described deadlock by this method because there is a synchronous version implemented by asynchronous:

```
public override AccessToken GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return GetTokenImplAsync(requestContext, cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
```

where GetTokenImplAsync(requestContext, cancellationToken) returns ValueTask and they may call .GetAwaiter().GetResult() on incomplete task.. Could be this the problem that I have? If so, how to workaround?

Answer (score 1):

`DisableAutomaticAuthentication=true`, I think it will always need user to login.

[Java SDK Doc:](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-identity/1.2.0-beta.1/com/azure/identity/DeviceCodeCredentialBuilder.html)

[image: Java SDK]

## [Try to use below code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/13940).

```
var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions()
{
    DisableAutomaticAuthentication = true
};
InteractiveBrowserCredential credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);
```